# Gigaflops of a processor

Tags: c, cpu, cuda, gpu, flops

I discovered my computer has NVIDIA CUDA Technology and I want measure the power of processing, in CPU and GPU.

Instead of searching for a program to do this, I want have a deeper understanding of how it works. What kind of code (C/C++) I need?

Comment: Have you started looking at the CUDA SDK?  http://developer.nvidia.com/object/cuda_3_1_downloads.html

Comment: Just keep in mind that different usages will show wildly different performances.  Some algorithms will simply not run well on a GPU.

Answer (score 7):

You need to download [CUDA SDK](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/cuda_3_1_downloads.html), some samples maybe and start your GPU programming. Then you should read some info about what are FLOPS actually and how to measure them correctly (start here [What is FLOP/s and is it a good measure of performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329174/what-is-flop-s-and-is-it-a-good-measure-of-performance) then some googling). Then do your tests :)

**PS**: I want to warn about CUDA and its performance. Marketing materials about CUDA and GPUs promise minimum x10 higher speeds than of any CPUs and your tests might get these values. But they are not *pure* FLOPS, GPU is not that universal computational device as CPU is and you will not achieve same results on *every* algorithm.