# How to measure FLOPS

Tags: c++, performance, benchmarking, flops

How do I measure [FLOPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS) or [IOPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOPS)? If I do measure time for ordinary floating point addition / multiplication , is it equivalent to FLOPS?

Comment: Do you mean "IPS"?  IOPS is something quite different.

Answer (score 9):

FLOPS is floating point operations per second. To measure FLOPS you first need code that performs such operations. If you have such code, what you can measure is its execution time. You also need to sum up or estimate (not measure!) all floating point operations and divide that over the measured wall time. You should count all ordinary operations like additions,subtractions,multiplications,divisions (yes, even though they are slower and better avoided, they are still FLOPs..). Be careful how you count! What you see in your source code is most likely not what the compiler produces after all the optimisations. To be sure you will likely have to look at the assembly..

FLOPS is not the same as Operations per second. So even though some architectures have a single MAD (multiply-and-add) instruction, those still count as two FLOPs. Similarly the SSE instructions. You count them as one instruction, though they perform more than one FLOP.

FLOPS are not entirely meaningless, but you need to be careful when comparing your FLOPS to sb. elses FLOPS, especially the hardware vendors. E.g. NVIDIA gives the peak FLOPS performance for their cards assuming MAD operations. So unless your code has those, you will not ever get this performance. Either rethink the algorithm, or modify the peak hardware FLOPS by a correct factor, which you need to figure out for your own algorithm! E.g., if your code only performs multiplication, you would divide it by 2. Counting right might get your code from suboptimal to quite efficient without changing a single line of code..

Answer (score 4):

You can use the CPU performance counters to get the CPU to itself count the number of floating point operations it uses for your particular program. Then it is the simple matter of dividing this by the run time. On Linux the perf tools allow this to be done very easily, I have a writeup on the details of this on my blog here:

http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/hpc-howto-measure-flops.html

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Answer (score 2):

FLOP's are not well defined. mul FLOPS are different than add FLOPS. You have to either come up with your own definition or take the definition from a well-known benchmark.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you use some well-known benchmark. Things like MIPS and megaFLOPS don't mean much to start with, and if you don't restrict them to specific benchmarks, even that tiny bit of meaning is lost.

Typically, for example, integer speed will be quoted in "drystone MIPS" and floating point in "Linpack megaFLOPS". In these, "drystone" and "Linpack" are the names of the benchmarks used to do the measurements.

IOPS are I/O operations. They're much the same, though in this case, there's not quite as much agreement about which benchmark(s) to use (though SPC-1 seems fairly popular).

Answer (score 1):

This is a highly architecture specific question,  for a naive/basic/start start I would recommend to find out how many Operations 1 multiplication take's on your specific hardware then do a large matrix multiplication , and see how long it takes. Then you can eaisly estimate the FLOP of your particular hardware

the industry standard of measuring flops is the well known [Linpack](http://www.netlib.org/linpack/) or [HPL high performance linpack](http://www.netlib.org/benchmark/hpl/), try looking at the source or running those your self

I would also refer to this answer as an excellent [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329174/what-is-flop-s-and-is-it-a-good-measure-of-performance)